# Networking woes : some physical and virtual machines are reachable and some aren't

Tags: networking, routing, virtualization

I had a sudden problem a few minutes ago (everything has been working fine for months until then), still going on :

The physical machines are

- a PfSense router
- a networking switch
- a KVM virtualisation server running a bunch of virtual machines :

  - one running HA proxy
  - different VMs running different applications

One interface is set up on the virtual host in a bridge, and used both for the host and all the VMs.

From the router (SSH connection), I can ping a few of the VMs but I can't ping either the virtualisation host, nor the HA proxy VM  -- as the HA proxy is unreachable, effectively all the machines are cut off from external connections, so all services are down.

From one of the available VM I can ping the host and the other VMs and connect to them through SSH. Obviously, the host and the unreachable VMs can't ping the router, or the internet (routes are set up correctly and didn't change).

The output from `arp -a` on the various machines reflect this : the router doesn't know the ethernet addresses for the host and some of the VMs; the VM that sees every other VM and host knows about all Eth addresses as expected.

Seeing that the router had a very long uptime I rebooted it just in case; nothing changed.

I thought of restarting the network switch but the serial console must be disconnected. I could reboot the virtualisation host too, but I'll have to go to the DC for that, I have zero confidence about what could happen if I simply rebooted in the current situation; will the network come up at all on the host? Of course the IPMI console isn't available from the router either, though it should be.

Any idea about what could be going on?

Comment: Before we can help you, you must, try the obvious first troubleshooting step: reboot your device’s safety and in a way you can recover them, if the reboot makes the situation worse.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've rebooted every device in the network, but only rebooting the network switch solved the problem once and for all...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1208781)

Comment: @Destroy666 Except its the same person

Comment: @RohitGupta what about that? The same person could also write "kittens are sweet", but that also wouldn't be an answer... You're supposed to be rating how helpful the answers are. This one is max 2/10 for me, 0 details, just "turn it off and on" kind of note which should have been done before asking, TBH.